# When do I choose React state Vs Redux Store

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, store

I've been learning Redux and a part I'm unclear of is, how do I make a determination between using react state vs redux store and then dispatching actions. from my reading so far it looks like I could use React state in place of Redux store and still get things done. I understand the separation of concerns with using Redux store and just having 1 container component and the rest of it as stateless component but how do I make the determination of when to use React state Vs redux store is not very clear to me. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a common dilemma faced by people who enter React Redux . But i;d recommend understanding the difference between Application state vs component state.

Comment: Dan Abramov (creator of Redux) [already answered this](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287).

Answer (score 63, accepted):

If the state doesn't need to be shared with other components, or the state doesn't need to be keep when the component is unmounted, then you can just put it in the component's state.

You can think that the Redux store is the database of front-end, if you have something like product data fetched from an API, then the Redux store is the right place; if you have a dropdown component, which takes a `isOpen` prop, then the parent of that dropdown can just keep `dropdownIsOpen` as a component state.

For more information, here is the answer from Dan: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/1287

Also you said

> only 1 container component and the rest of it as stateless component

This is incorrect. You can have several container components. A container component can also contain another container component.

Comment: Yep.  Also see these answers from the Redux FAQ: http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-only-redux-state , http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-multiple-components .

Answer (score 5):

From book:

> First of all, we should always keep in mind that only the minimal
>   amount of data needed should be put into the state. For example, if we
>   have to change a label when a button is clicked we should not store
>   the text of the label, but we should only save a Boolean flag that
>   tells us if the button has been clicked or not. Secondly, we should
>   add to the state only the values that we want to update when an event
>   happens, and for which we want to make the component re-render.
>   Another way to figure out whether the state is the right place to
>   store information is to check if the data we are persisting is needed
>   outside the component itself or by its children. If multiple
>   components need to keep track of the same information, we should
>   consider using a state manager like Redux at the application level.

Answer (score 1):

You're absolutely right. Redux (and flux architecture in general) are only formalism tools to help for building large apps. They're not necessary at all.

There's actually an interesting post called You might not need redux by Dan Abramov, the creator of redux that might give you a better answer than I do: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367#.7093fm1z8

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things that need to be grasp

**State of component:** If you want to keep state-specific to your HOC then use state. Now in the function component, we use useState.

**State of redux:**  If you want to share data throughout the application use redux state.

**Store of redux:** It's nothing but a database for the redux library. In the case of redux, we can have only one store. To use multiple stores we can use Flux but it will make things more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If state is needed only for that particular component then prefer to use react state.
For example using state for UI actions

If any state you want to use across the component/project then go with redux state.
For example API response data etc

For detail understanding refer this link

https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/06/07/react-state-vs-redux-state/