# What are the advantages of using Redux with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, state

Reading [this](https://medium.com/@blairanderson/you-probably-dont-need-redux-1b404204a07f) article I wonder: What are the advantages of using `Redux` over/with `React`? I am aware that Redux and React are two different things. I used `Redux` to keep the `state` of my Application. But reading the article, I can exchange the `state` (between `Components`) of the Application with `react` just as easy as I would with `Redux`.

What are the advantages of using `Redux` oder `React` then?

Comment: Redux does not replace React, they are different things. That article seems to make that distinction.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are using Redux `with` React, not `over` React. React is view library, and Redux helps you manage state of the application. If you are building huge application, it is going to get increasingly difficult to manage state throughout the components, if you are using solely React.

However, in smaller applications with few modules React should be sufficient and Redux might be overkill.
Really depends on your use case.

I recommend you read when you should use Redux, as said on FAQ of redux docs.
http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/General.html#general-when-to-use

As Dan Abramov (creator of Redux) said - 
`I would like to amend this: don't use Redux until you have problems with vanilla React.`

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that it depends on the situation. Sometimes you can simply use React state and sometimes it's simpler if you use Redux state instead of passing through props back and forth the React state.

Here are some articles that can help you decide when and what to use:

- http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-only-redux-state
- https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/06/07/react-state-vs-redux-state/

Here is a question answer that is on the same topic.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41585031/6055311

Answer (score -1):

If you have a common data which is shared between pages, redux is the way to go. But if your data only lives in a single page, you can use react.

Comment: as the examples shows, common data can be shared across pages with *react* as well!