# reducers updating state directly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, reducers

I am trying to learn react in proper way.

what I learnt in react is we should not update state directly and so we need too use setState.
But in my reducers they are updating state directly.
 Can you tell me how to fix it. 
Providing my code snippet below. 
Is this the correct way of updating reducers.

```
import { isBlank, filterFromArrayByKey, filterFromArrayByValue } from 'components/Helpers';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    tab: 'operational',
    search: '',
    region: '',
    county: '',
    SPORT: '',
    SPORTCounties: [],
    loading: false,
    error: '',
    operation: {},
    lookup: {},

    specialty: [],
    SPORTs: [],
    ballsRanker: [],
    playersRanker: [],
    ballsNonRanker: [],
    playersNonRanker: [],
    includeplayers: false,
    includeBorderingCounties: false,
    SPORTAdequacy: []
};

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    console.log("state.zoomDefault--->", state.zoomDefault);

    delete state.zoomDefault;
    console.log("state.zoomDefault--->", state.zoomDefault);

    // console.log("state.errorMessage--->", state.errorMessage);

    delete state.errorMessage;
    // console.log("after delete state.errorMessage--->", state.errorMessage);
    switch (action.type) {



        case SET_SPORTS:
            //console.log('action.Rankeyload-->', action.Rankeyload);

            state.ballsRanker = state.copyballsRanker;
            state.ballsNonRanker = state.copyballsNonRanker;
            state.playersRanker = state.copyplayersRanker;
            state.playersNonRanker = state.copyplayersNonRanker;
            if (action.Rankeyload.lenght > 0 && !state.excludingContactee) {
                for (let i = 0; i < action.Rankeyload.lenght; i++) {
                    state.ballsRanker = state.ballsRanker.filter(item => !item.SPORTRankerStatus.find(SPORT => SPORT.SPORT == action.Rankeyload[i].value));
                    state.ballsNonRanker = state.ballsNonRanker.filter(item => !item.SPORTRankerStatus.find(SPORT => SPORT.SPORT == action.Rankeyload[i].value));
                    state.playersRanker = state.playersRanker.filter(item => !item.SPORTRankerStatus.find(SPORT => SPORT.SPORT == action.Rankeyload[i].value));
                    state.playersNonRanker = state.playersNonRanker.filter(item => !item.SPORTRankerStatus.find(SPORT => SPORT.SPORT == action.Rankeyload[i].value));
                }
            } 
            else {
                state.ballsRanker = state.copyballsRanker;
                state.ballsNonRanker = state.copyballsNonRanker;
                state.playersRanker = state.copyplayersRanker;
                state.playersNonRanker = state.copyplayersNonRanker;
            }
            return { ...state, SPORTs: action.Rankeyload };




        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Reducers *have* to update their state directly. It's the component state that you have to update through `setState`

Comment: @SergeK. can you tell me why, it will help me to understand

Comment: Maaybe you should take a look over [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41584647/when-do-i-choose-react-state-vs-redux-store).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use destructuring and do something like this.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    tab: 'operational',
};

export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {

    switch (action.type) {
        case SET_SPORTS:
            return {...state, tab: action.tab};



        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

or you could use the [React Immutability helpers](https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html) for nested updates.