# What's the difference between useContext and Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

What's the difference between useContext and Redux?
Redux is like useContext?
When I use Redux on my project, I don't need useContext anymore?

Comment: Redux doesn't get rid of `useState`. Redux lets you share state between components at multiple levels.

Comment: I'd recommend a Redux tutorial and see if that answers your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do I choose React state Vs Redux Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41584647/when-do-i-choose-react-state-vs-redux-store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux is your global state from which your components receive their state through *mapStateToProps*.
As I said, it is your application-wide single source of trough. While useState is used to manage (parts of) the state in a single component.

You might not want to keep every small piece of component state in your global store, for example, show a loading spinner (loading: true) in a certain component while an operation is running or display certain parts of the component depending on the users' actions.
Data you want in your global store is data you need to use in multiple components and/or you need it available throughout the lifecycle of your application.

I hope this helps a bit.