# What are best practices for storing state in react using redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, state

I am working on a native runtime app, and am new to using redux in my react applications. Is is best practice to store ALL state in the redux store, or should I only store state that I know I need to access anywhere, and then continue to write state inside of components that I know are only needed inside of that specific component.

I guess my question really is, how do I determine what state to store inside of components, and which state to store inside of the redux store?

Comment: There's no general answer--it depends on what yoir app needs. It doesn't make much sense to store state used by a single component/module in Redux, though, but the precise delineation will always depend on app architecture, libraries, uses, etc.

Comment: would like to add that you might not need redux... don't use just for using it (unless using it is what you actually want...) depending on your problem, context API would be more suited to your problem...

Comment: Two points: 1. The Redux DevTools browser extension is really useful for debugging. That's a valid reason to store something there. 2. Redux can only store data that's serializable. So you have to use component state for things like callbacks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do I choose React state Vs Redux Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41584647/when-do-i-choose-react-state-vs-redux-store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if a state uses more than two screens then you should use redux , for example customer name , you can see it on home screen and profile screen you can use redux , when you change information in the personal information screen, the home screen will be updated.

state should only be used in 1 component

Hope the answer helps you!